# Numpy Array Shape Issue

Tags: numpy

I have initialized this empty 2d `np.array`

`inputs = np.empty((300, 2), int)`

And I am attempting to append a 2d row to it as such

`inputs = np.append(inputs, np.array([1,2]),  axis=0)`

But Im getting

`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

And Numpy thinks it's a 2 row 0 dimensional object (transpose of 2d)

`np.array([1, 2]).shape`

> (2,)

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Notice the shape of your inserted array when you do:
`np.array([[1, 2]]).shape`

Comment: `(2,)` is a 1d array.  It's not a transpose of anything else.

Answer (score 3):

To add a row to a `(300,2)` shape array, you need a `(1,2)` shape array.  Note the matching 2nd dimension.

`np.array([[1,2]])` works.  So does `np.array([1,2])[None, :]` and `np.atleast_2d([1,2])`.

I encourage the use of [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).  It forces you to think more carefully about the dimensions.

Do you really want to start with [`np.empty`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html)?  Look at its values.  They are random, and probably large.

`@Divakar` suggests `np.row_stack`.  That puzzled me a bit, until I checked and found that it is just another name for `np.vstack`.  That function passes all inputs through `np.atleast_2d` before doing `np.concatenate`.  So ultimately the same solution - turn the `(2,)` array into a `(1,2)`

Answer (score 0):

Numpy requires double brackets to declare an array literal, so

`np.array([1,2])`

needs to be

`np.array([[1,2]])`

Comment: Both create arrays, one has shape `(2,)`, the other `(1,2)`, 1d and 2d.  I don't know what you mean by `array literal`.

Comment: @hpaulj: I would hazard that redress is trying to say _"to literally translate the matlab array literal `[1, 2]` into a numpy, you [sometimes] need an extra set of brackets"_

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to append that as the last row into `inputs`, you can just simply use `np.row_stack` -

```
np.row_stack((inputs,np.array([1,2])))
```

Please note this `np.array([1,2])` is a `1D` array.

You can even pass it a `2D` row version for the same result -

```
np.row_stack((inputs,np.array([[1,2]])))
```

Comment: Never heard of `row_stack` before!  `vstack` yes. :)

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, apparently, its not even documented :)